# R, warning sequencing in for loop

Tags: r

In R, a function inside for loop is not printing warnings in sequence.

```
for(i in sample(-2:2)){
  cat(sprintf("running for %d\n", i))
  j= sqrt(i)
}

#running for 0
#running for -2
#running for 1
#running for -1
#running for 2
#Warning messages:
#1: In sqrt(i) : NaNs produced
#2: In sqrt(i) : NaNs produced
```

The **warning messages are printed at the end** and it is not clear for which values we get warning. I am looking for warning massege sequence as

```
#running for 0

#running for -2
#Warning messages:
#1: In sqrt(i) : NaNs produced

#running for 1

#running for -1
#Warning messages:
#2: In sqrt(i) : NaNs produced

#running for 2
```

How can I force R to print warning in sequential way (or print warning immediately after the execution of code)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a `immediate.` parameter in the `warning` function especially for that purpose, try setting in your function

```
if (i < 5) warning("A warning", immediate. = TRUE)
```

eg.

```
foo <- function(i){
  if (i < 5) warning("A warning", immediate. = TRUE)
  i }

for (i in 3:7){
  cat(sprintf("running for %d\n", i))
  foo(i)
}

# running for 3
# Warning in foo(i) : A warning
# running for 4
# Warning in foo(i) : A warning
# running for 5
# running for 6
# running for 7
```

---

**Edit**: Per your new update, you will probably need to wrap your function up into `tryCatch`, something like

```
set.seed(222)
for(i in sample(-2:2)){
   cat(sprintf("running for %d\n", i))
   tryCatch(sqrt(i), warning = function(w) message(paste(w, "\n")))
}

# running for 2
# running for -2
# simpleWarning in sqrt(i): NaNs produced
# 
# 
# running for -1
# simpleWarning in sqrt(i): NaNs produced
# 
# 
# running for 1
# running for 0
```

Comment: Thanks, I will keep this mind when I will write my own function. However a general approach where there is no need to modify function foo will be great.

Comment: All your function `foo` is doing is to generate a warning, so its not clear what you are after. Maybe try improving your example an way that `foo` will do something else which will require a warning

Answer (score 0):

From `?options` the option `warn` is listed to fill this role. It's not really the best option; `tryCatch` is most likely cleaner provided the warnings are being used correctly but it's useful for debugging.

> warn: sets the handling of warning messages. If warn is negative all
>   warnings are ignored. If warn is zero (the default) warnings are
>   stored until the top–level function returns. If 10 or fewer warnings
>   were signalled they will be printed otherwise a message saying how
>   many were signalled. An object called last.warning is created and can
>   be printed through the function warnings. If warn is one, warnings are
>   printed as they occur. If warn is two or larger all warnings are
>   turned into errors.

```
options(warn=1)
for(i in sample(-2:2)){
    cat(sprintf("running for %d\n", i))
    j <- sqrt(i)
}
#running for -2
#Warning in sqrt(i) : NaNs produced
#running for 2
#running for 0
#running for 1
#running for -1
#Warning in sqrt(i) : NaNs produced
```

You could also use something like:

```
currentWarnLevel <- getOptions("warn")
# code that should print warn straight away
options(warn = currentWarnLevel)
```

If you're using a custom logger I found it best to override `options(warning.expression)` and using `withCallingHandlers` and then reset `warning.expression`.